# Separate numbers from a String

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, query-string

I am currently working on an artificial intelligence ROBOT named "PokeBOT".
I have made it purely in Java.
I have successfully made its first version (check it here -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fz9P3JIkHbM&feature=youtu.be).
But it's not too good.
Now I want to upgrade it.
That's where I need your help.

I want to take an input as `String` and separate the numbers from it..
Can I do it ??
Here's what I exactly want to do...

```
INPUT: Add 25 And 25
OUTPUT : 50

INPUT: Subtract 50 From 100
OUTPUT: 50
```

Here I can use `Input = Input.toUpperCase();` and the `Input.contains("ADD");` function to detect addition, subtraction, etc.
If this is possible, then please help.

Thanks in advance!!

PokemonGamer

Comment: Use regular expressions https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @Florian  Can You Please Share The Code ?? I Have Trouble Understanding It...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Remember we are not a free coding service ;)  **YOU** are the one that should provide a minimal code with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
//Pattern for numbers only  
String pattern = "^[0-9]+$";
// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
// Split string by whitespaces
String[] inputArray = input.splitString(' ');
//iterate through splitted string
for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length;i++){
  //create Matcher
  Matcher m = r.matcher(inputArray[i]);
  //check if match found
  if(m.find(){
    //number
  else{
    //no number
  }
}
```

This code is not tested. Just wrote down out of memory. Might have some bugs/errors.
If you want also something else eg. floatingpoint numbers you have to change the pattern, look here  [docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.ht‌​ml](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)